# GTKsharp windows 8 style fullscreen app

Tags: c#, xamarin, mono, gtk#

I am a beginner in GTK# and was wondering if the following app could be developed in GTK#/Mono/Xamarin as shown?
[GTK Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KRqFY.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Possibly, I think you need to give it a try and see what you can come up with. GTK# has basic widget called a DrawingArea, which you can do a lot with if you are prepared to draw your own widgets and spend some time learning about how. You will need to familiarise with two key libraries - Cairo and Pango. Cairo is a drawing library, Pango is a text rendering library. With these you can do most things, including some pretty funky graphics.

Comment: I am familiar with DrawingArea. I doubt Cairo allows drawing transparent windows.

Comment: Yes this would be a challenge though I can't say for certain it isn't I think you are right to doubt it. I guess it depends how important that is vs. using GTK#!